# SVN external not working

Tags: svn

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.jmfeurprier.com/2009/12/10/simple-introduction-to-svn-externals/), but to no avail.

I need to include an svn repository as a folder within another repository. I am using TortoiseSVN.

RepoA: folder, containing, file1 and file2.
RepoB: many files

I created a folder in RepoB, named the same as RepoA. Then I set the new folder's property `svn:exported` to the url of RepoA.

I SVN upodate RepoB, but the files do not appear in the new folder. What am I douing wrong?

Comment: Instead of SVN:exported use svn:external and before check out, for the first time align the target folder with "UPDATE to head" command

Comment: There is not a single mentioning of 'exported' in that tutorial you followed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is called svn:externals, not svn:exported.

Comment: `Error parsing SVN propert svn:externals`. What could this error message mean?

Comment: This, and the format is `url folder`, while I was putting only url in.